# Using "cycle" in smarty template system?

Tags: php, smarty

Here's my current code:

```
{foreach from=$items item=item name=utable}

{foreach from=$item.terms item=tmp name=titem}
<tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">

REMOVED UNNECESSARY CODE FROM HERE

{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

The values `odd` and `even` are rotating correctly for the `tr` class.

However, the rotation doesn't restart with every new table.  For example, I want the first `tr` of every table to have the class `odd`, but if the last table ended with `odd`, the next one keeps on starting with `even`.

Is there any way to make it the cycle stop at the end of each table and restart at the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `reset` attribute together with `print`.

Sample PHP data:

```
$data = [1 => [2,3,51], 2 => [5,6,1], 4 => [1,2,21]];
$smarty->assign('tables',$data);
```

Sample Smarty file:

```
<style>
    tr.odd {
        background: red;
    }
    tr.even {
        background: #fff;
    }
    table {
        margin: 50px 0;
    }
</style>


{foreach $tables as $table}
    {cycle values="" reset=true print=false}
    <table>
        {foreach $table as $row}
        <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
            <td>
                {$row}
                </td>
        {/foreach}
    </table>
{/foreach}
```

As alternative you can do it also this way:

```
{foreach $tables as $table}
    <table>
        {foreach $table as $row}
        {if $row@first}{assign var="reset" value=true}{/if}
        <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even" reset=$reset}">
            <td>
                {$row}
                </td>
         {assign var="reset" value=false}
        {/foreach}
    </table>
{/foreach}
```